# Accessing function from *_test package

Tags: module, go

I have a package `pkg`. The test for package `pkg` are in *_test.go* files. However to initialize a test runner I need a a function from other package which I can't import in `pkg` because of circular dependecy.

My idea is to use `pkg_test` package.
Is there any way to access test functions (in *_test.go* files) from `pkg` in `pkg_test`?

My project structure:

`├── f.go          # package pkg
├── f_test.go     # package pkg
├── init_test.go  # package pkg_test`

In other words: I want to access a function from *f_test.go* in *init_test.go* or vice versa (access a function from *init_test.go* in *f_test.go*. Is there any way to do it?

PS: in *f_test.go* I can't import `pkg_test`

Answer (score 2):

This is generally a good opportunity to:

- either move the function from pkg_test in pkg
- or mock whatever the function from pkg_test is doing, in order to not rely on that initialization, through an interface (like [mocking database](http://tonyhb.com/building-a-testable-golang-database-layer))

Trying to go around that limitation is trying to work around the dependency issue rather than solving it.

That being said, if you can import pkg in pkg_test, then yes, you can access a function from `f_test.go` in `init_test.go`.

Comment: I can't move the function to pkg (because it requires other package which in pkg will make circular dependency - it's a common test initializer). I don't any way to import `pkg` in `pkg_test` - is there any one?

Comment: @RobertZaremba not that I know of. I usually make sure I can mock whatever initialization I need instead of trying to depend on it.